# Messages not making into elasticsearch

Tags: logstash

We are a setup with three queues in rabbitmq, handling three different types of logs.

The queues are handled by logstash, and given a tag, and then logstash dumps the message into the appropriate index in elasticsearch.

So my input looks something like this:

```
input {
  rabbitmq {
    host => "localhost"
    queue => "central_access_logs"
    durable => true
    codec=> json
    threads => 3
    prefetch_count => 50
    port => 5672
    tags => ["central_access_log"]
  }
```

And similar setup for the other two queues:

My output is like this:

```
if("central_access_log" in [tags]){
  elasticsearch {
    host => "localhost"
    index=> "central_access_logs"
  }
 }
```

I suspected for a while that not everything was making it into the central_access_log index (the other two indexes, more of less, seemed fine), so I added this:

```
file {
 path => '/data/out'
}
```

And let that run for a few weeks.

Recently, I noticed that for the last week and half, *nothing* has been coming into that index (again, the other two are perfectly fine), however the text file contains all the missing messages.

How can I go about debugging this? Is it an error on logstash's end, or elasticsearch?

Comment: Anything in the logstash or elasticsearch log files?  Elasticsearch will, for example, drop messages where the data doesn't have a compatible type to the mapping.

Comment: Elasticsearch logs are basically empty.
The logstash logs reported an out of memory exception on Nov 2nd, but this extends before and after that date.